# Backup ActiveStorage images in PostgreSQL rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, backup, rails-activestorage

I am trying to make a backup in the database with active storage, but I do not know where the images are stored. I did a pg_dump but I only got the data from the tables. Do you know how I could do it?

I am using a local ubuntu 18 lts server with postgresql to store the images.

Comment: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#downloading-files

Comment: What service are you using to store files? Active Storage ships with a few different adapters to store files.

Comment: excuse me, im using the local server. I have a ubuntu server 18.04 lts.

Comment: Check your ActiveStorage configuration to find the directory your files are in, probably `storage/` at the top of your app's directory tree.

Comment: Yes! the files are in that ubication, i copied the folder storage in the other server with the same database and app but didnt work. The app doesnt show the pictures :(

Comment: Now works!! i forget install the FFmpeg and muPDF applications. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There are implementations of ActiveStorage::Service that save the image data directly to the database.

Here's one such implementation.
https://github.com/lsylvester/active_storage-postgresql

Usually not a good idea to store lots of binary in an RDBMS.
However, if it's relatively few and simplifies your architecture, it may make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. At the moment I will keep the traditional method of storage.